# Calculating Area of Polygon

Tags: coordinate-system, area

I am trying to calculate the area of polygons in a shapefile on QGIS 2.2.  My project is in an equal area conic projection with OTF projection activated.  When I added a new field called 'AREA' and used the $area function in the field calculator, I got impossibly small numbers.  I then switched the CRS on the shapefile from the properties menu from NAD83 to the same US Equal Area Conic and tried to calculate again with the same results.  Do I need to make a copy of the shapefile and set to the CRS that way?  Or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Is your data extent focused locally to a particular city or state or is it broad spanning multiple states/countries?

Comment: It is focused on the Continental US

Comment: Did you check your project's settings ("Project" "Project properties..." "General" "Measurements" "Units for area measurement"? The result of $area depends on those settings.

Comment: So after doing that I still have areas that are too small...closer, but still too small.

Comment: Also, my measurement tool is working, that is how I know the areas are so far off.